# using jna with FAR PASCAL custom dll

Tags: dll, jna

I am using JNA to access a custom DLL which seems to be using the FAR PASCAL Calling Conventions, but the JVM crashes every time i try to access it.

Development Guide of the dll says:
BOOL FAR PASCAL GetIomemVersion(LPSTR);

And Dependency Walker tells me:
_GetIomemVersion@4

```
public class PebblePrinter {
    public interface Iomem extends StdCallLibrary {
        boolean _GetIomemVersion(String version);
    }    

    String version;  
    Iomem INSTANCE;  
    StdCallFunctionMapper myMapper;

    public PebblePrinter() { 
        HashMap optionMap = new HashMap();
        myMapper = new StdCallFunctionMapper();
        optionMap.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, myMapper);
        INSTANCE = (Iomem)Native.loadLibrary("iomem", Iomem.class,optionMap);
    }
    public String getIomemVersion(){
        INSTANCE._GetIomemVersion(version);
        return version;
    }
}
```

With C# code it works well using

```
[DllImport("iomem.dll", EntryPoint = "_GetIomemVersion@4")]
public static extern bool GetIomemVersion(IntPtr version);
```

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

I've just used the wrong parameter ..
GetIomemVersion needs a Pointer

```
boolean _GetIomemVersion(Pointer version);


public String getIomemVersion(){    
   Memory m = new Memory(1024);
   Pointer x = m.getPointer(0);
   INSTANCE._GetIomemVersion(x);
   return x.getString(0);   
}
```